# Position and float problems with categories tree?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a simple category tree for a shop and I have a problem, its look like that:

[image: The big space]

Question is how to fix its that big space that appears `root-cat:hover`, can anyone explain whats problem and what a solution.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lp51heqL)

Copied some html and css that I have in my tree, hope it will help.

Comment: It does not look like that in your fiddle, so it is very unclear what you actually ask

Comment: There is a built in jsfiddle on SO, please use this in the future

Comment: You can find it to the right of insert image

Comment: updated fiddle,forgot to add float:left chek it out:https://jsfiddle.net/Lp51heqL/6/

Comment: Problem is when subcategory div appears,next root is moving down and there is a big space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add these rules, which will fix things for the first sub menu and partly for the other ones:

```
root-cat {
    position: relative;
}
.sub-cat {
  position: absolute;
  left: 260px;
  top: 8px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eLat18Ls/1/

Note: To have the other submenus appear not at the top of their page, but beside their main menu entries, you have to nest the sub menus into their respective main menu entries (in the HTML). Usually, this is done with unordered lists: `ul` and `li` elements. Just google for how to build a menu using ul and li

Comment: Thank you!Works perfectrly.